# C++ make program cmd friendly

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, parameters, console

I am trying to create a C++ console app and to create new command.

Exemple of what I want to do:
In terminal: `(program name) (a value for exemple a string)`And then the program make something depending on the value of the string

What is the easiest way to do this using visual studio 2017?

Comment: I think you are looking for `int main(int argc, char * argv[])`, but that';s about all I can get from your question. I recommend that you clarify what you are after. You also might be asking the question too soon and not really have a question yet.

Comment: This is a direct duplicate of the on hold question https://stackoverflow.com/q/54612258/10663732

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can do

1. Open your project's property window,
2. Go to "Configuration Properties" -> "Debugging" -> "Command Arguments"
3. Put your values to "Command Arguments"

To accept this value in your app, your main function should be of signature like

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

For example "Command Arguments" is set to `aaa 123 bbb` then the arguments' values are:

```
argc = 4
argv = {"program_name", "aaa", "123", "bbb"}
```

Hope this is more convenient than manually giving arguments from command line.

Comment: We should use the `wmain` entrypoint in Windows, which provides the OS native command-line arguments as UTF-16LE strings. Transcode to UTF-8 if necessary. Try to avoid the legacy ANSI and OEM encodings -- at least until it's common for most systems to use Windows 10+ with the system locale encoding set to UTF-8, which may take about 5 years.